# Date and Javascript

Tags: javascript

So, I know this is probably a FAQ, but I can't seem to unravel it in my head.

In Javascript, I'm trying to create a count down timer without the use of cheating (meaning, borrowing someone's script), for our wedding date which happens to be in September.

I've know learned how difficult it is to convert days into Months and Days.

For those math guru's out there, is it possible to define each month in javascript and use it to count down, then follow up with an if statement that if the date passes, this is how many days have passed. I like math but I can't seem to figure out the formula and it's frustrating me.

Sept 22 is the day.

I know there are 183 days by time of this writing. I also hand counted the days to verify. I can get the formula to show me this.

But would it be a long winded "if statement" to include all of the months if I defined every month and the amount of days in that month? Or could it be a long expression?

```
variable = weddingDate - (?)
```

I don't need it writen if someone can just help with some alegbra! :)

---

Edit

```
var d1, d2;

d1 = new Date('3/23/2012');
d2 = new Date('9/22/2012');

compare = d2-d1

document.write((compare) /1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

So this returns the accurate number of days. This was actually much easier than people's made it out to be. I know I can change d1 that will auto update depending on the PC's date.

But, what's the formula to accurately convert from days into months and days?

I know you could take

```
 document.write((compare) /1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

And change to

```
 document.write(((compare) /1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) / 30.4368499);
```

Then I could round to nearest integer which would be 6 (aka 6 months), then subtract that from the total, leaving me a decimal amount. I could then times this by 30.4368499. But I wasn't sure if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Congrats on getting married! :-)

Comment: `variable = weddingDate - Date.now()` that should do the trick if you make weddingDate a date object. The resulting object can then be manipulated to find the days, months, and time until then.

Comment: @jzworkman: `Date.Now` should be `Date.now()`.

Comment: uhh ... no.  That will not work, @jzworkman - the result will be a number representing the difference in seconds between the two dates.

Comment: Yea I typed that too fast, I meant it could then be manipulated to get the days, months, etc. Edited above.

Comment: Instead of thinking about the dates as dates in the usual sense, think of them as the number of seconds/milliseconds from the epoch.  In that sense each day has its own value.

Comment: I added an update. This thought made it easier but how does one covert from days to months and days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaScript Date object can give you a value that represents the "distance" between the date and a point in the past called the "epoch".  By subtracting two such values, and then dividing by the number of seconds in a day, you can get a count of days.

Look up the `.getTime()` method. (Simply subtracting one Date from another actually works, because JavaScript will coerce the objects to numbers and the way a Date object becomes a number is effectively to call `.getTime()`.)

(Not writing code because you wisely asked for just the process.)

Comment: Thank you. I'm still confused at converting from days to months and days though. How is that formula created?

Comment: Ah, well that's a different story. It's actually kind-of tricky because months have different numbers of days in them. One thing you can exploit, however, is the fact that the JavaScript Date object has a `.setDate` method that's "smart". If you set the day-of-month with that function to a day past the end of the month (like 32), it rolls over to the next month. So you could write a loop that increments the day-of-month and counts how many times the month value changes!

Answer (score 1):

```
var END_TIME = new Date("2012-11-11").getTime(); // replace 2012-11-11 with actual weddding day
if (new Date().getTime() > END_TIME) {
  alert("WE MADE IT");
}
```

For more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: While that works, I'm trying to compare two dates and post it up on my website so we can login to see how many days are left. So I'm trying to convert from days to months and days.

Answer (score 0):

// Months are tricky- if you wanted **weeks** and days, you'd be done now...

// I assume that on the 22 of each month you want to return the number of months and no days, and so on.

```
function bigDay(d){
    var now= new Date(),
    days1= now.getDate(),
    months1= now.getMonth(),
    days2= d.getDate(),
    months2= d.getMonth(),
    days= 0, months= months2-months1,
    daysinmonth= (new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 0)).getDate();
    if(d-now<0) return '';
    if(months> 0){
        if(days1>days2){
            days= (daysinmonth-days1)+days2;
            --months;
        }
        else days= days2-days1;
    }
    else days= days2-days1;
    return months+' months '+(days?' and '+days+' days.': '');
}
```

alert(bigDay(new Date(2012, 8, 22)))

// you can use document.write or innerHTML or whatever)